# Access OneDrive Directories and files using MSGraph API with client Authentication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have been trying to use the MSGraph API to access files in a shared OneDrive which is part of a 365 account.
I need to create an app that gets client permissions and then makes the API calls.
Specifically this must be done with client authentication (not delegated - on behalf of a signed in user)

The question is how can I get a directory list of what's in my oneDrive using MSGraph?
Then I need to be able to download specific items.

The steps I did are

1. Register an Azure and copied the account details and secret (works fine)
   added all the permissions I need.
2. In Postman, I requested the required Auth2 bearer token (works fine)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/V2.0/token
```

This correctly returns a bearer token

3. In postman I used this to get my drives
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/
   Shows one drive with Name "Documents" and an id value
4. In postman I tried to list the items in the drives with

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/{{driveId}}/items
```

This returns:
"code": "invalidRequest",
"message": "The 'filter' query option must be provided."

5. In postMan I tried to search to find a specific file I know is in the oneDrive

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='todo.txt')
```

This returns and empty array [] - when I can see that the drive contains this file

The question is how can I get a directory list of what's in my oneDrive using MSGraph?
Then I need to be able to download specific items.

EDIT:
I got the drive id from this Postman request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives
which returned:
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
"value": [
{
"createdDateTime": "2022-02-12T14:09:19Z",
"description": "",
"id": "**b!3JFpYb83RUidS4Xkt71Orcfzp9sQsf1Kmr_43UsnyqL4nAuvo6oYRIAe-gp_shCu**",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-01-10T03:57:29Z",
"name": "Documents",
"webUrl": "https://agcwainc.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",

I then used the id to try to find its contents:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveID}}/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7B%7BdriveID%7D%7D/root/children)
which returns and empty array:
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b%213JFpYb83RUidS4Xkt71Orcfzp9sQsf1Kmr_43UsnyqL4nAuvo6oYRIAe-gp_shCu')/root/children",
"value": []

The app permissions are:
[image: App Permissions]

The Onedrive contents is:
[image: OneDrive Contents]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First validate your App Registration has the correct permissions and Admin Consent has been granted.

| API / Permission Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Files.Read.All | Application | If you only need to read files |
| Files.ReadWrite.All | Application | If you need to read and upload files |

To get all files at the root level of the a drive you can use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root/children
```

Get all files inside of a folder of a drive

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{folderName}:/children
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Note: See a full answer below from bcperth based on info provided by Brian Smith.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I read all the doco including the reference you provided. I have all permissions. This is what I get from the /root/children which is an empty array.  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b%213JFpYb83RUidS4Xkt71Orcfzp9sQsf1Kmr_43UsnyqL4nAuvo6oYRIAe-gp_shCu')/root/children",
    "value": []

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.

Verify permissions are correct on the app registration, you are getting a token that is from that app registration and for Microsoft Graph scope (jwt.io to verify), admin consent is granted on that app registration for the API Permissions requested, drive Id being used is correct, and lastly there truely are files in that drive. You should have a return there.

Comment: Ok thanks for persisting. If the token was not there or bad, it returns a "token invalid" error. If the permissions were bad it returns an "unauthorised" error. See the edits for details of the setup. I'm guessing the driveID returned is not not what I think it is - although its a valid drive id or the API would say invalid id!.  Is there any other way to get the driveID for say the drive shown in the image above? Apologies I'm a React/AWS programmer and not that familiar with MS.

Comment: I should also confirm the decoded token, shows it came from  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com", and its permissions are "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "People.Read.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All"
  ],

Comment: Also  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users" returns the correct array of users (of the 365 account" , verifying the app/authentication/authorization is set up correctly. "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives" returns a single drive, but https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveID}}/root/children shows an empty array but as per edited question it contains the file todo.txt.

Comment: The permissions look good and I see admin consent is granted. You are using the correct DriveID also. I would try throwing a bunch of files into the drive for giggles and see if it returns something then.

Comment: I put 3 more files in the drive but its still showing [ ]. Either its the wrong drive id, or I need some body parameters (none now) or ??? I'm fairly sure the request would be rejected if say the account type did not support client authentication - like for a personal account.

Comment: If you are interested I can give you the Azure and office logins and you can have a play on PostMan or similar. There is nothing secure - just some golf club stuff. I'm close to telling the (pro Bono) client to copy his files to AWS where I can easily reach them, but I hate to be beaten!  my email is brendan@bcperth.com - thats Perth Australia.

Comment: Thank you for solving this in our Teams session. I have ticked up your answer and accepted it. I will post the complete solution shortly with appropriate accreditations

Comment: @Brian_Smith Thanks again for your patience and support to solve this for me. I have now written up a full process in a reply with full acknowledgements where they belong!

Answer (score 1):

The full process to access files in OneDrive from a client authenticated nodejs process is:

1. Register an app with Azure and get a client secret
   Put app parameters into postman as environment variables
2. Assign permissions ( needs admin authority) to access whatever Azure services you want to access. In this case its Files.ReadWrite.All
   To access target OneDrive files using MSGraph:
3. First request a token like below:
   [image: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/V2.0/token where TenantID is one of the variables from Step 1.]
   This should return an object with an access-token attribute.
4. Instead of looking for drives with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/
   ask for the users instead https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
   Note: You need to set the authorisation header in all MSGRAPH requests as below:
   [image]

This will return a list of users and their userIDs along with other meta data.

5. Search the above array of user and find the user who owns the drive you want to access. The ask for that users drives with
   [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{user_id}}/drives](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7Buser_id%7D%7D/drives)
6. Then pick the drive you want and display its contents with [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{drive_id}}/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7B%7Bdrive_id%7D%7D/root/children)
7. How to download a file depends on where the code is being run from nodejs or from a browser. For the case node there is an MSGraph command to download the content of a file. This wont work with Javascript because of CORS issues. Instead, the request in 6) includes a signed URL  for each file  that can be passed to fetch or axios etc to read the contents.

Acknowledgment: Brian Smith provided the guidance to solve this problem for me. Please +1 his reply and not mine!!

Comment: Thank you for the question and for consolidating the answer. I spent two days on this, and I can finally get my code working :)